# import in python working on my Linux Terminal but raising ModuleNotFoundError on VS code

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror, ubuntu-22.04

I am very beginner to Linux as I recently started using it. I installed different libraries like numpy, pandas etc.
`import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd`
It raises a ModuleNotFoundError in VS Code. But when I run the same code in Terminal, there's no issue.
Note: I installed these libraries with
`pip3 install package`
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

I tried to uninstall the package and reinstall but still not working. I also tried to install by
`sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`.
Nothing works out.

Answer (score 1):

Without all the context, it sounds like you have a few different python environments.

In terminal check which python you are using `which python`
In VSCode settings check `Python: Default Interpreter Path`

That might help you understand what is going on.  Make sure that the VSCode python path is the same path that your terminal prints out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two or more interpreter of python.

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P**" and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct python interpreter in VsCode.